# Angular 2 referring to controls for validation messages

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I'm trying to get validation messages to work in Angular 2. There have been so many changes to Angular 2 that there doesn't seem to be an elegant solution on the internet (so please don't mark this as duplicate).

Currently, to show validation messages on my model driven form I'm doing this:

```
<div class="form-group">
     <label for="name">Name</label>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" formControlName="name">
     <div class="text-warn" *ngIf="!addUserForm.controls.name.pristine && !addUserForm.controls.name.valid">
        Please enter a name
    </div>
</div>
```

The formbuilder of my component looks like this:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.addUserForm = this.fb.group({
        name: ['', [Validators.required]],
        email: ['', [Validators.compose([EmailValidators.normal(), Validators.required])]],
        phone: ['', [Validators.compose([UniversalValidators.isNumber(), Validators.required])]],
        address: this.fb.group({
            addr1: ['', [Validators.required]],
            addr2: [''],
            addr3: [''],
            city: ['', [Validators.required]],
            zip: ['', [Validators.required]],
        })
    });
}
```

I remember that I used to be able to get validation messages to display by using a simple `*ngIf="!name.valid"` but now I can't seem to get it working without referring to the whole form group (`*ngIf="!addUserForm.controls.name.valid"`). If I do it the short way I get an error message about `valid` being undefined (presumably because I can't refer to the control directly, for some reason).

There must be a less verbose way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I remember that I used to be able to get validation messages to display by using a simple `*ngIf="!name.valid"` ...

I think it is possible with **`Template driven forms`** not with **`Reactive forms/Model driven forms`**.

I also think, with **`Reactive forms/Model driven forms`**, this is the only way because you have to tell angular2 that with which **`formGroup`**, a particular control is attached to...

Comment: Hm, maybe I was using a template driven form in my previous project. Is there a better way to do these validation messages, or am I stuck with writing out the whole path to the control every time?

Comment: I think with Reactive forms/Model driven forms, this is the only way because you have to tell angular2 that with which formGroup, control is attach to.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to implement a `get` function in your component. So you'd do:

```
get name() { return this.addUserForm.get('name') }
```

Once you do that, in your html template you can use the syntax you were looking for.

```
*ngIf="!name.valid"
```